# Color palette not balanced in R

Tags: r

I am trying following code for a color palette. However, it shows more green than other colors. Why is this and how can this be corrected? Thanks for your help.

```
mypal = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"))
pie(rep(1,100),col=mypal(100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking into [this page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/colorRamp.html) and learned that there are at least two parameters you can play with. One is **bias** and the other is **space**. It seems to me that space ="Lab" affects the colour pie on my computer screen. With my eyes, I can perceive more purple like colours in the pie now. It is probably worth playing with the two parameters more and see what kind of change you can perceive with your eyes. I hope this will help you. This was good learning experience for me.

```
mypal = colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"), bias = 0.5, space="Lab")
pie(rep(1,100),col=mypal(100))
```

[image]

If I set bias at 0.9, this is the outcome.
[image]

If I set bias at 0.1 This is the outcome
[image]

Comment: It is certainly better but I expected all 4 to be equal. Red and yellow still cover very small area.

Comment: I just updated my post. If bias is at 0.9, it seems that we have the results you want??? I see pretty good even proportion for each of the four colours.

Comment: It is much better with 0.9 but if you note, 1/3 is green, 1/3 is yellow and 1/3 is blue+red together.

Comment: We all perceive colours in different ways. My perception of the colours in the pie (with bias = 0.9) seems different from yours. I do not see green occupying 1/3 of the pie, for example. space = "Lab" creates smoother and more uniform colour ramps. The other option is space = "rgb". `interpolate()` is another parameter. I played with it yesterday, but the change I saw was subtle. If you still need to control colours, you may want to write your own function, I guess.

Comment: I rather perceive 6 colours. Blue, purple, green, yellow, orange, and red.

Comment: Bias <1 compresses red side, while bias>1 compresses blue side (including green). I found bias of 1.1 to be the best. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Good to hear that. I somehow thought bias stays between 0 and 1. I learned another thing from you. Thank you.