# How to widen bar of color palette in R

Tags: r

How can I create a bar having following color palette for checking:

```
colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"))(100)
```

I can draw a pie chart to see spread of colors ([Color palette not balanced in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382110/color-palette-not-balanced-in-r)) but how to create a linear bar? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: 
As suggested by baptiste in comments below, following works but produces a very thin bar. How can I widen it and preferably have a horizontal bar?

```
grid.raster(colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"))(100))
```

[image]

Comment: `grid::grid.raster()`

Comment: You can either change the title of your question, or answer it and open a new question about widening the bar.